# Read emails from axigen server using python

Tags: python, email

Is there any implemented library or solution to read emails(get attachments too) from an Axigen server using Python?

I've done it before with the `email` library and the `gmail api` but i cannot find any documentation on axigen.

Is there any difference or you could connect just like you would do to any other `imap` or `pop3` server?

Any hit would be useful,

Thank you!

Comment: IMAP, SMTP and POP and standard protocols. If they are enabled by the axigen server, you can use it without worrying what exactly the server is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axigen implements standard IMAP and POP3 servers so you can use either to retrieve messages.

E.g. with IMAP you would do something like this (you need to add error checking, etc) to retrieve the subject of the oldest message from the INBOX folder:

```
import imaplib
import email

M=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("server.com")
M.login("user", "pass")

typ, data = M.select("INBOX")
typ, data = M.fetch(1, '(RFC822)')

eml = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
subject = eml['Subject']
```